# How do I determine significant differences between patient data normalised per individual to 100% (therefore having no SD) and the response decrease?

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation, normalization

Patients have very different levels of hormones etc naturally so when measuring the effect of a drug designed to decrease this hormone we normalise each patients original score to 100 (%). Then we can fairly look at the % decrease in this hormone in each patient and compare them regardless of initial value.

However this means the initial value has no standard deviation (as they are all 100) and I'm led to believe I cannot then use a t-test or similar?

How do I determine if the difference is significant?

Thanks!
A

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting with all the initial values the same, you would not use the initial values in the analysis but instead treat the difference values as your measurement of interest.

In this case, you can use the a one-sample t-test to test if the mean of the difference is statistically different from zero.

This will be the same as using a paired t-test with the initial and final values.

Non-parametric alternatives to this approach include the one-sample sign test and one-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test.

Practically speaking, you want to think about the best approach with this kind of data.  As @Llopis suggests, even if the initial values vary, you don't need to normalize them.  You can analyze the difference between before and after values, or look at, for example, the percent change.  Retaining the initial values may give you additional information, for example if the change is greater for those with higher initial values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you transform these values to something like this:

```
Value       Pre   Post
Patient A:  100     8  
Patient B:  100     8   
Patient C:  100     4
```

But to calculate a reduction you don't need transform your initial values to 100. Example (where the above values come from):

```
              Pre       Post     Reduction
Patient A:  150000     12000   12000/150000*100 = 8%
Patient B:  160000     12800   12800/160000*100 = 8%
Patient C:   1800       800     800/1800*100    = 4%
```

Then you can compared with a paired t student if there are differences between Pre and Post. In this example the p-value is 0.1812